# Is there a RegistryKey.GetValue() parameter value that can be used to return the file path of an installed program?

Tags: c#, registry

Using the following code I am able to iterate and record all names and versions of installed programs on my PC, specifically through making use of the RegistryKey.GetValue("DisplayName") and RegistryKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"). 
Is there another such parameter that allows me to find the installed program's file path.

Thanks.

```
        string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
        using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
        {
            foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                {
                    ThirdPartySoftware thirdPartySoftware = new ThirdPartySoftware((string)sk.GetValue("DisplayName"), (string)sk.GetValue("DisplayVersion"));
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/uninstall-registry-key

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to find. Thank you very much.

Comment: (I just googled `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and it was the second hit)

Comment: There's no guarantee that anything under the Uninstall Key that will lead you back to "the" executable for a product. At best, there's an `UninstallString` but that's just something to execute to remove the product - not even guaranteed to be in the same directory as "the" executable. Raymond Chen discusses the various ways that the [Add/Remove Programs feature guesses](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493) based on registry information, etc.